# regression analysis for dataset with few predictors and few samples

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, small-sample

I have a small pilot dataset containing experimental measurements for 12 samples, 4 numeric predictors and 1 numeric outcome variable. The goal is to obtain a first rough estimate on the extent to which the outcome variable can be predicted using one or more of the 4 predictors, before deciding on whether it's worthwile to collect more data. With the lm-function in R, I obtain a linear fit with p < 0.05, if I include only the best predictor in the model. However, given that this is only pilot data with a very small sample size, and that all 2^4-1 = 15 feature subsets were tried, is it sufficient to adjust the p-value for the best predictor for multiple hypothesis testing (e.g. using Benjamini-Hochberg adjustments) to gain confidence in this model?

Would it make sense to apply any other modelling techniques to obtain more confidence that the data has significant predictive information content (non-linear approaches will most likely lead to over-fitting on such a small dataset, but maybe other linear models, e.g. ridge regression, linear SVM, could still be informative) - or is this not worhtwile due to the worsening of the multiple testing problem?
Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I wouldn't be thinking about p-values in this setting. The biggest danger is using some method you think should give you confidence in your model, rather than using the data as it is - exploratory data.